# Why does the Image multiply and not change the position?

Tags: javascript

Why does the Image multiply and not change the position by pressing up or down?
The ufo also just multiply why?
The rocket schould only move up and down.
The Ufos schould move vom right to left and spawn every second.
I only change the coordinates.
So the ufo and rocket schould not multiply.

```js
"use strict";

let keySpace = false;
let keyUp = false;
let keyDown = false;
let canvas;
let drawer;
let ufos = [];

let rocket = {
  x: 10,
  y: 180,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  src: "rocket.png",
};

document.onkeydown = function(e) { //Keypressed
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    keySpace = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    keyUp = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    keyDown = true;
  }
};

document.onkeyup = function(e) { //KeyUp
  if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    keySpace = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    keyUp = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    keyDown = false;
  }
};

function start() {
  canvas = document.getElementById("ID");
  drawer = canvas.getContext("2d");
  load();
  setInterval(update, 1000 / 25);
  setInterval(createUfo, 1000);
  draw();
}

function createUfo() {
  let ufo = {
    x: 650,
    y: Math.random() * 450,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    src: "ufo.png",
    img: new Image(),
  };
  ufo.img.src = ufo.src;
  ufos.push(ufo);
}

function update() {
  if (keyUp) {
    rocket.y -= 3;
  }
  if (keyDown) {
    rocket.y += 3;
  }
  ufos.forEach(function(ufo) {
    ufo.x -= 3;
  });
}

function load() {
  rocket.img = new Image();
  rocket.img.src = rocket.src;
}

function draw() {
  drawer.drawImage(rocket.img, rocket.x, rocket.y, rocket.width, rocket.height);
  ufos.forEach(function(ufo) {
    drawer.drawImage(ufo.img, ufo.x, ufo.y, ufo.width, ufo.height);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```css
canvas {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <canvas id="ID" width="720" height="480"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I briefly refactor your code and prepared a pen:
https://codepen.io/Zaaburin/pen/BaxVxMb

```
function draw() {
  update();
  drawer.clearRect(0,0,720,480);
  drawer.drawImage(rocket.img, rocket.x, rocket.y, rocket.width, rocket.height);
  ufos.forEach(function (ufo) {
    drawer.drawImage(ufo.img, ufo.x, ufo.y, ufo.width, ufo.height);
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

start()
```

Comment: Please avoid using external websites to share your code and instead you could make a [mcve] directly in your answer.